# Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am trying to upload a file into one drive using Microsoft Graph API's through a console application. I have created a appsettings.json file to store my client & tenant ID. But when i am trying to access it through loadappsetings() function its returning the above error. I have attached the code and error screenshot,As i am new to API's in c# ,any kind of help would be good.The code is  below.**Thanks in advance.**

```
 private static IConfigurationRoot LoadAppSettings()
    {
        try
        {
            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", false, true)
            .Build();

            // Validate required settings
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(config["applicationId"]) ||
                string.IsNullOrEmpty(config["applicationSecret"]) ||
                string.IsNullOrEmpty(config["redirectUri"]) ||
                string.IsNullOrEmpty(config["tenantId"]))
            {
                return null;
            }

            return config;
        }
        catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

[[image: this is the debug result]

Comment: Presumably because your `appsettings.json` file doesn't exist in the location it expects. Where, exactly, is your `appsettings.json` file and is it being copied into your project's working-directory on-run?

Comment: NEVER ignore the exceptions! If you didn't, you would get a helpful message where the code expects the file!

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I actually had misplaced my file location. Instead of storing it in debug folder, i had stored it in the outside folder.. Thanks for the help